# Identifying language of 1840s document in West Indies

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, translation

I have an old document that was submitted to a governmental office in the West Indies.  The file that the document originated from had other documents in French, English and Danish. I can't identify the language.

The document is from 1836-1840 and appears to be a response to or an explanation to get relief from fines owned to a port authority. My best understanding of the situation. 2 family members are mentioned in the document.

Can you help identify the language?

https://hj4321.webs.com/anahuac.htm

Comment: The words I can identify are Latin or Danish (possibly some other Scandinavian, but's what's the chance?). Are you sure this isn't Danish?

Comment: It could be Danish since it was a document sent to gov office located in Danish West Indies.  Can u write down the words u identified? Thank you.